# Most flexible free mailing service to be used with PHP

Tags: php

I need one that allowes me to

- update the mailing list from service From my PHP code

  - sending single new users From my code
- send single messages to specified user From my code
- send 'updates/news' to all users From my code

Something is telling me to go for feedburner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phplist might be worth a look.

We use mailchimp for the mailing list sending, and postmark for the single email sending.

Comment: thanks! i'm looking for postmark but there are several results in google with same name for this.. can you link me to the one you mean? thanks!